# Ubuntu 14.04 - BUG? SSH login failing

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ssh, password, macbook

Ubuntu 14.04 - installed apt-get install openssh-server, username is sun and password is 1234 and root also has password 1234.

Remotely connecting and failing to allow me.

```
suns-MacBook-Air:js sun$ ssh sun@192.168.1.6
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).

suns-MacBook-Air:js sun$ ssh sun@192.168.1.6
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sun@192.168.1.6's password: 

suns-MacBook-Air:js sun$ ssh root@192.168.1.6
root@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.6's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@192.168.1.6's password:
```

EDIT: PC is using ipv4 and ipv6

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:fd:84:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.6/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:a03f:24af:bd00:898f:6294:6b5e:94f6/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 345642sec preferred_lft 85306sec
    inet6 2a02:a03f:24af:bd00:d6be:d9ff:fefd:84fe/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 345642sec preferred_lft 345642sec
    inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:fefd:84fe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:3e:84:01:bf:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I skipped right to the end of the question and hadn't noticed you were trying to log in with a normal user account to begin with. The following explains why remote `root` login doesn't work by default in Ubuntu. Either way, it seems to have helped.

For the normal user stuff, just look in `/var/log/auth.log`. It'll tell you exactly what the problem is and that should give you a fairly decent idea of what you need to do.

But for root issues, there's a little block in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes
```

That's the default and it means it'll only allow SSH key based authentication for root.
It won't allow you to log in with a password.

Obviously you could change the setting to `yes` but you're starting to unravel the security of Ubuntu. Having a working root login (especially with a super-crackable password) is usually a pretty awful (and unnecessary) idea. It would be easier to just use a SSH key.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the user's own account doesn't work.

Comment: @muru Fair point, added a block at the top for it.

Comment: NO - its working now since i followed Oli suggestion, it was my mistake, the username was not sun but it was sun1